# Too much data while sending / saving an image from Android to Windows via WiFi

Tags: android, c++, windows, image, wifi

I have an Android Application (Android 5.0) which should send an image via WiFi to a Laptop using a C++-Program on Windows 7 (implemented with boost library).

When I send the image, the Laptop receives the correct amount of Bytes sended by the Android device. However, when I want to save the image to a file, there are more Bytes saved than I have received. Therefore, I am not able to open it. I get the message that the image is too big or damaged. On a closer look in notepad++, the binary data seems to be correct except that there are a few empty lines too much on the side of the laptop.

An Example:

**Image Sended:**
Length 273650
Lines 1975
Words 31088

**Image Received and Saved**:
Length 274663
Lines 1979
Words 31088

The Laptop receives 273650 Bytes via WiFi but extends the file while saving. Deleting the lines manually didn't solve the problem either. There is still too much data in the saved file.

***Android Code***

```
try {
     final OutputStream outputStream = streamSocket.getOutputStream();
     final ByteArrayOutputStream bufferStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

     thermalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bufferStream);

     bufferStream.flush();
     (new Thread() {
         @Override
         public void run() {
             super.run();

             try {
                 synchronized (streamSocket) {

                     bufferStream.writeTo(outputStream);
                     outputStream.flush();
                 }

                 bufferStream.close();

             } catch (IOException ex) {
                 Log.e("STREAM", "Error sending frame: " + ex.toString());
             }
         }
     }).start();

} catch (Exception ex){
         Log.e("STREAM", "Error creating PNG: "+ex.getMessage());
}
```

***C++ Code***

```
void do_read()
{
    auto self(shared_from_this());
    socket_.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(data_, max_length),
        [this, self](boost::system::error_code ec, std::size_t length)
    {
        if (!ec)
        {                   
            std::string test = std::string(data_, length);

            std::ofstream myfile("Test.png", std::ios::app);
            if (myfile.is_open())
            {
                myfile << test;
                myfile.close();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Any Idea what could be the problem? I am relatively new to socket programming. Every help is appreciated.

Comment: You should certainly not use string I/O to save binary data. And why aren't you compressing the image directly to the socket output stream? You don't need the intermediate `ByteArrayOutputStream` at all. It is just a waste of time and space.

Comment: I will change that, thanks for the reply. But it didn't fix the problem.

Comment: The part about the streams isn't the problem. That's why I posted it as a comment instead of an answer. The part about strings is defintely at least part of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not likely to be about sockets, it should be all about binary data being written as text.

Try replacing

```
std::ofstream myfile("Test.png", std::ios::app);
```

with

```
std::ofstream myfile("Test.png", std::ios::app|std::ios::binary);
```

EDIT: Why do you open the file in append mode? You should write one PNG image per file.